# Sumproduct, Sumif, Indirect and named ranges issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have this formula that works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(Financials&"!$B3:$B10000"),'Information PG1'!$K$2,INDIRECT(Financials&"!d3:d10000")))
```

where Financials is a named range.  If I change the actual name to another named range it works but how do I enable the formula to work where I can select the named range from a drop down list as I have 8 named ranges that I need to use.

Answer (score 1):

Go to where you want to keep your dropdown list (e.g. cell A1) Create a drop down box with data validation (Data > Data Validation > Data Validation), create a list of the names of your 8 named ranges

[image: Data validation]

Then you can replace `Financials` with `INDIRECT(A1)` in your formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(A1)&"!$B3:$B10000"),'Information PG1'!$K$2,INDIRECT(INDIRECT(A1)&"!d3:d10000")))
```

Comment: Thank you - it now works fine.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Rob Please accept the answer by checking the tick next to my question if it helps.  Thanks :)